# Rails gets wrong class when two classes have the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

In my Rails I have the following models:

A STI sub-class

```
class Subscription::Discount < Subscription
  def self.new_with_url
    ...
  end
end
```

and another model class (doing completely different things, this is a STI base class)

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So in my controller, I uses `Subscription::Discount` when I create users:

```
@user.subscription = ::Subscription::Discount.new_with_url()
```

However it complains: `undefined method 'new_with_url' for #<Class:0x007fbb499c6740>`

I think Rails is not calling the right class with `new_with_url`. On top of that I am not sure what `#<Class:0x007fbb499c6740>` is. So, two questions:

1. Without renaming any model, how can I reference `Subscription::Discount` properly?
2. Why is the error message saying `#<Class:0x007fbb499c6740>`, I can understand if it is  `Discount` instead of that anonymous class.

EDIT:

Here are all the relevant models:

```
app/model/discount.rb
app/model/coffee_discount.rb (CoffeeDiscount < Discount)
app/model/subscription.rb
app/model/subscription/discount.rb (Subscription::Discount < Subscription)
```

Comment: Is this STI class in your model folder?

Comment: yes, it is, let me edit the post and list all the relevant class

Answer (score 0):

The method is named `create_with_url` but you're calling `new_with_url`.

Fix the method name.

Comment: oh sorry that's my typo when i copied and pasted the wrong method, there are two of them but I only showed on for simplicity

Comment: Ok. If you define `self.new_with_url` in your `Discount` class, does *it* get called?

Comment: Yes I just tried it with Rails.logger.debug and it got called and output the log.

Comment: If that's really the case, consider [raising an issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues) at github.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to make a minimal project to demonstrate that

Comment: I think it is todo with this issue (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6931). Can you change your answer to that and I'll accept it?